# How create revisor observable in rxjava

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

**Problem**
I have many observables, that periodically emits items.
I need for every running task(observable), running revisor observable, that for example logs execution time, emitted results!, etc.

**Example**: when user(subscriber) subscribes on observable, revisor observable starts. It's should be transparent to subscribers

How best way to do that?

Comment: did you have a look at the `doOnNext`, `doOnError` operators? all of them are also combined in the `doOnEach` operator that receives `Notification` (which you can inspect to see if it was a onNext, onError or onCompleted)

Comment: No, i didn't. Thanks, I will try